# Solvability by radicals

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I study the book "Introduction To Field Theory" by Iain Adamson (https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToFieldTheory), and struggle with the Theorem 26.5. on page 166:

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero. If the polynomial $f$ in $F[x]$ is solvable by radicals, then the Galois group of any splitting field of $f$ over $F$ is solvable.

Adamson defines "solvable by radicals" on page 160/161:

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero; a field $E$ containing $F$ is said to be an extension of $F$ by radicals if there exists a sequence of subfields $F = E_0, E_1, ..., E_{r-1}, E_r = E$
such that for $i = 0, ..., r- 1, E_{i+1} = E_i(\alpha_i)$, where $\alpha_i$, is a root of an **irreducible** polynomial in $E_i[x]$ of the form $X^{n_i} - a_i$.
A polynomial $f$ in $F[x]$ is said to be solvable by radicals if there exists a splitting field of $f$ over $F$ which is contained in an extension of F by radicals.

I don't see where in the proof of Theorem 26.5 the irreducibility of $X^{n_i} - a_i$ is used. Why does Adamson require the polynomial to be irreducible?

**Update**, July 8th.: I would like to add some definitions. Let us call a radical extension with irreducible polynominals $X^{n_i} - a_i$, an irreducible radical extension. And a polynominal with splitting field contained in an irreducible radical extension, solvable by irreducible radicals. When Adamson says "solvable by radicals", he actually means "solvable by irreducible radicals". In the cited Theorem Adamson then states: "If the polynominal is solvable by irreducible radicals, then the Galois group is solvable". But I think what he actually proves is the stonger statement: "If the polynominal is solvable by radicals, then the Galois group is solvable". Don't be confused when you read the theorems in the book: Adamson does not use the term "solvable by irreducible radicals".

Comment: It's a valid question, but ultimately, I don't think that it matters that the polynomial be irreducible. In fact, in Dummit and Foote, this polynomial is neither assumed nor required to be irreducible.

Comment: That feels very strange to me. How do we get the roots of unity with only irreducible polynomials of the form $x^n-a$? I suspect it may be wrong.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Why do you think it's wrong? Adamson proves: If the polynominal is solvable by irreducible radicals, then the Galois group is solvable (See update above) But when it is solvable by irreducible radicals, it is clearly solvable by radicals. And then the galois group is solvable, as is proved in many textbooks.

Comment: Hmm, may be it does work. I missed the fact that you don't need to get to exactly the splitting field. A bigger field will do also. I couldn't see a way of getting the splitting field of for example $x^7-1$ as an extension of irreducible radicals. But I think $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7,\zeta_3)$ can be reached by irreducible radicals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably so the Galois group of the extension $K_n(E_{i+1})/K_n(E_i)$ is easier to handle. Consider, for instance, $\mathbb Q(\mathrm i,\sqrt2)/\mathbb Q(\mathrm i)$ (the $\mathrm i$ is the root of unity he adjoins at the beginning of the proof). This is the splitting field of $X^4-4$ over $\mathbb Q(\mathrm i)$, but also of the minimal polynomial $X^2-2$ of $\sqrt2$. The order of the Galois group is the degree of the minimal polynomial. If we choose the minimal polynomial to construct our extension, we can read off the order of the cyclic factors directly. If reducible polynomials were allowed, the orders of the groups would not be readily available. It would also make the degree $n$ of the polynomial $X^n-e$ whose roots he adjoins at the start unneccessarily large. I don't think any of these matter for the proof, but maybe he considered it more elegant?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also think that the irreducibility is not needed. This would answer my question.

Comment: But I would like to add some more thoughts. In Theorem 26.4 Adamson proves the reverse theorem: If the galois group is solvable, then the polynominal is solvable by irreducible radicals. Together with Theorem 26.5 in its stronger version (See update above), this would imply: "If a polynominal is solvable by radicals, it is also solvable by irreducible radicals." This seems not trivial to me. Is the statement correct?

Comment: About your update: He does actually only prove the weaker version: Solvable by irred. radicals $\Rightarrow$ Galois group solvable. But the stronger version is still correct. So it's true that if a polynomial is solvable by radicals, its Galois group is solvable, which implies that it is also solvable by irreducible radicals. But yeah, this doesn't seem trivial to me, either. At least I can't think of a proof which doesn't rely on the theorems 26.4/5 and the related theorems about solvability by (reducible) radicals, and those are pretty non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right, he only proves the weaker version. But what I meant is, when you go through the prove step by step, nowhere the irreducibility is used. So the same prove can be used to prove the stronger version.